# Javascript add listener for objects by classname

Tags: javascript

I want to add 'click' listeners to dynamically created elements. My code is:

```
function addListenerToElements (){
        var aTags = document.getElementsByClassName("classElements")
        for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
            aTags[i].addEventListener('click',myFunction);
        }
    }

    function myFunction() {
        console.log("something");
    }
```

but it doesn't work(there is no errors in console)

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: I'm using firefox

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying dynamically added elements, event delegation would be the better way to go. Below works for both static elements, but also for dynamically added ones:

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("div.className")) {
    console.log('element clicked', e.target.innerText);
    // or call your function
  }
});
var index = 0;
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(index++));
  div.className = 'className';
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="className">a</div>
  <div class="className">b</div>
  <div class="className">c</div>
  <div class="className">d</div>
  <div class="className">e</div>
</div>
<button id="add">Add Element</button>
```

Comment: unfortunatelly I can not add id to container

Comment: Then use the class of the container, or the parent node of the first element @PaulGerbert

Comment: I used class of the container but it returns array(?) and then tried to add listener to every elements from array but doesn't work

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0] @PaulGerbert

Answer (score 0):

Ok you missed something here, the events wont register until you call the function

```
addListenerToElements();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xrqnn20f/1/

```
addListenerToElements();
function addListenerToElements (){
        var aTags = document.getElementsByClassName("classElements")
        for (var i=0;i<aTags.length;i++){
            aTags[i].addEventListener('click',myFunction);
        }
    }

    function myFunction() {
        console.log("something");
    }
```